# Testing functions in Jest -

Tags: javascript, jestjs

The console.log outputs the correct string but Jest keeps failing. Am I missing something?

This is the test:

```
const filterDesignationNum = require('./function on a specific NEO.js');

test('Filter NEOs by designation number', () => {
  expect(filterDesignationNum).toMatch('Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)')
});
```

This is the function I am trying to call:

```
//Analysis Display all NEO's that have a specific NEO

const fs = require('fs');

const neowiseData = fs.readFileSync("C:\\Users\\adamb\\Downloads\\NEOWISE_Dataset.json", 'utf8');

const neowiseDataObj = JSON.parse(neowiseData);

function filterDesignationNum(designationNum) {
    const displayNEOData = neowiseDataObj.filter(neo => {
        return neo.designation.includes(designationNum);
    });
    displayNEOData.forEach((neo) => {
        console.log(`Designation: ${neo.designation}`);
        console.log(`Discovery date: ${neo.discovery_date}`);
        console.log(`Observed Magnitude: ${neo.h_mag}`);
        console.log(`Minimum Orbit Intersection Distance: ${neo.moid_au}`);
        console.log(`Perihelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_1}`);
        console.log(`Aphelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_2}`);
        console.log(`Orbital Period: ${neo.period_yr}`);
        console.log(`Orbital Inclinatio: ${neo.i_deg}`);
        console.log(`Hazardous: ${neo.pha}`);
        console.log(`Asteroid or Comet Class: ${neo.orbit_class}`)
        console.log('------------------------');
    });
}
filterDesignationNum(419880)

// Export the function as a module.
module.exports = filterDesignationNum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
expect(filterDesignationNum).toMatch('Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)')
```

Compares your function (which is an object) with the string which is wrong, and if you call it:

```
expect(filterDesignationNum(419880)).toMatch('Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)')
```

It would fail again as you are not returning anything from `filterDesignationNum`. You can make that function return so it makes your code easily testable:

```
function filterDesignationNum(designationNum) {
    const displayNEOData = neowiseDataObj.filter(neo => {
        return neo.designation.includes(designationNum);
    });
    return displayNEOData.reduce((acc, neo) => {
        return `${acc}
        Designation: ${neo.designation}
        Discovery date: ${neo.discovery_date}
        Observed Magnitude: ${neo.h_mag}
        Minimum Orbit Intersection Distance: ${neo.moid_au}
        Perihelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_1}
        Aphelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_2}
        Orbital Period: ${neo.period_yr}
        Orbital Inclinatio: ${neo.i_deg}
        Hazardous: ${neo.pha}
        Asteroid or Comet Class: ${neo.orbit_class}
        ------------------------\n`
    }, '');
}

console.log(filterDesignationNum(419880));
```

Then in your test you can either check the content of your returned values:

```
expect(filterDesignationNum(419880)).toMatch('Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)');
```

Or, if for some reason you want to check the value is printed to the console, you can [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) the `console` object and expect `console.log` [to have been called with](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) a [string containing](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringcontainingstring) a piece of your input:

```
const consoleLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.stringContaining("Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything, you can modify your code like that to return the string :

```
function filterDesignationNum(designationNum) {
    const displayNEOData = neowiseDataObj.filter(neo => {
        return neo.designation.includes(designationNum);
    });

    // create an array to store the output strings
    const output = [];

    displayNEOData.forEach((neo) => {
        output.push(`Designation: ${neo.designation}`);
        output.push(`Discovery date: ${neo.discovery_date}`);
        output.push(`Observed Magnitude: ${neo.h_mag}`);
        output.push(`Minimum Orbit Intersection Distance: ${neo.moid_au}`);
        output.push(`Perihelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_1}`);
        output.push(`Aphelion Distance: ${neo.q_au_2}`);
        output.push(`Orbital Period: ${neo.period_yr}`);
        output.push(`Orbital Inclinatio: ${neo.i_deg}`);
        output.push(`Hazardous: ${neo.pha}`);
        output.push(`Asteroid or Comet Class: ${neo.orbit_class}`)
        output.push('------------------------');
    });

    // join the array into a single string and return it
    return output.join('\n');
}
```

Don't forget to update your jest test to check the function :

```
const filterDesignationNum = require('./function on a specific NEO.js');

test('Filter NEOs by designation number', () => {
  expect(filterDesignationNum(419880)).toMatch(`Designation: 419880 (2011 AH37)\nDiscovery date: ...\n`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have used this on anther function.